# MIPS not recognizing NULL

Tags: string, null, iteration, mips

Forgive me for the easiness of this question but I am new to MIPS and am getting an odd error:

```
.data

myString: .asciiz "P5"


.text


li $v0 4

la $a0, myString
newLoop:
    syscall
    addi $a0, $a0, 1
    beq $a0, $zero, done

    j newLoop

done:
    li $v0, 10
    syscall
```

My program never terminates despite the fact that there is a null character (as I have gleaned from other posts, equivalent to $zero) at the end of myString. I would have thought that $a0 would point to "P", then "5", then "\0" and then jump to done and terminate.

Thanks for your eyes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're comparing to zero is the address, not the value at that address. You need something like:

```
lbu $t0,($a0)       # load the byte pointed to by $a0
beq $t0,$zero,done
```

Comment: Many thanks Michael. So what I am doing by comparing pointers is saying if they literally point to the same spot in memory, rather than if they have the same value? Is it therefore true that whenever comparing strings I have to dereference them?

Comment: Yeah, what you're doing now is checking if `$a0` is a NULL pointer, not if it points to a NULL byte.

Comment: By "what you're doing now", you mean what I originally wrote but you're solution is for the NULL byte, right?